# How can I make it not possible to type after reaching a max number of lines in my textarea?

Tags: unity, gui

I have a EditorGUI.TextArea that is 300x100 in size. How can I make it impossible to type after reaching a max number of lines in my textarea (no wrapping)?

Comment: Max length of characters, or maximum number of lines, as in they are hitting enter in there?

Comment: @TimHolt Maximum number of lines. Enter wont make a new line.

Comment: Ah so basically word wrap is going to occur, and you don't want word wrap to allow for more than a certain number of lines.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "(no wrapping)" and "Enter wont make a new line"? Does that mean that the text field has no wrapping set and that the users newline commands are ignored? If so how would you enter a new line in the first place? Are you using the standard Input field to enter text into the box or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do this in Unity, but you need some way to monitor the text as the user types it in.  If you can do that, then you can calculate the render size of what is typed in using the [Font.GetCharacterInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Font.GetCharacterInfo.html) method, and with that calculate and count how many line breaks occur due to word wrap.  Given you know how many line breaks occur, you can know how many lines have been entered.

What you have to do is start calculating the render width of the string character by character, starting at the beginning of the string.  As soon as you reach your width of 300 pixels, you know that a word wrap needs to occur.

At that point, if it happens when you are looking at a space or the first character of a word, the word wrap will occur then.  If it happens in the middle of a word, you are going to have to back up character by character until you find a space where you can do a word wrap.

After each word wrap, increment your count of how many lines occur in the text, and start your measurement up to the 300 pixels again for the next word wrap.

Once your count of lines reaches some maximum you've got in mind, you could do something like disable the submit button (if there is one), and display an error message to the user that there are too many lines.